# Как вызвать функцию перед закрытием программы?

Tags: python

Дана функция `save_file()`. Её нужно вызвать перед завершением программы.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вставить её перед функцией close_program().

Comment: @splash58 это немного другой язык

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если требуется безусловно выполнить после завершения программы, обычном или при ошибке

```
def save_file():
    print('exit')

def main():
    print('работа программы')
    raise KeyboardInterrupt('выход')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    finally:
        save_file()
```

out:

```
работа программы
exit
KeyboardInterrupt: выход
```